# TesseractOCR: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, dll, ocr

I'm a little programer with a big ilusion in this world haha, but recently i've got a big trouble with my program.

Recently, i've started a new project: Convert an image (with text in) to String, for personal purposes. I'm using TesseractOCR 5.3.1 library con VB.net (IDE Visual Studio Community 2022). The program works perfectly in some computers (i've tested in all my computers: 3 (of 6)) sucess pass, 3 with the following error:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.DllNotFoundException: Failed to find library 'leptonica-1.83.1.dll' for platform x64

Yes, i'm sure that in my "x64" folder, that file exists.
Yes, i've copied that file for the root folder of my application.
Yes, i've copied too to System32 and SysWOW64 folder, same result.
Yes, i've tried to unistall the OCR pluging and reinstalling.
Yes, i've compiled my app into x86 version, same result, with the difference the error displays "for plataform x86" instead.
Yes, i'm runing as administrator, and i'm disabling my antivirus software (WIndows Defender).
Yes, i've moved them for shorts paths, same result.

I repeat: The program works fine in 3 computers without any issue. I'm thinking about their proccesors, because where my application works, all processors are Intel Core iX, meanwhile the trouble machines are Intel Core 2® X (Duo and Quad).

I don't know what i've to do so, i'm going being crazy.

Hope you can help me son. Thank you :)

PD: Sorry for my bad english, i'm not using translators.
PD2: Grettings from Venezuela :)

[Root directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7aSy.png)
[x64 folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SlFf.png)

All description are in the main post.

Comment: Windows will report "file not found" for a variety of errors.  It may be that a dependency of the dll is missing.  It may be that it's the wrong bit width (not sure .NET returns the file not found error for this problem but I'm informed VBA does)---though this isn't likely for a case where it's only failing on certain machines but works on others.  "Loader snaps" (can be set using the gflags tool from the Windows platform tools) may help diagnose the problem if you can run under the debugger.  This tool will add verbose tracing to the debug output for loading libraries.

Comment: Hello. When you talk about "attach a debugger", you mean run step-by-step using the own Visual Studio? Or  what? Olly? If i use Olly it will be hard hehe... 

So, my idea is install Visual Studio in the failing machine and run my project there using his own debugger (step-by-step).

Comment: Visual Studio is probably easiest, if it's installed on the machine which has problems.  Otherwise, maybe you need to use something like WinDbg.

Comment: UPDATE:  @Craig . Before to try the Debbug method, i've found a tool called "Dependency Walker", its information is not very clear but i've noticed that de DLL was not detecting "VCRUNTIME140.dll", so i've searched some information in the web and IA and i found the microsoft installer for fixing the problem. My system is x64, so i've downloaded x64 version and x86 (only in case of needind it). I've installed the x64 version first and tried again to launch the function of my App, stills failling, so i installed x86 version and compiled a x86 version of the VB.net app, tried and surprise! Works.

Comment: So, my question is: Why x86 version is working and the x64 isn't? I've tried before the x86 version and failed to, so, why its working now and the x64 still failing?